# Salesforce Android Hybrid ライブラリを使ったアプリが特定端末でプッシュ通知が届かない

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

Androidアプリで下記のSalesforceモバイルライブラリを利用するにあたって、
Androidの3台中１台はプッシュ通知が届かない。

https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android

発生したAndroid端末は
・機種：Xperia 10 IV
・Android OS：12

問題発生前は通常にプッシュ通知は届けますが、
アプリを複数回インストール・アンインストールしてから問題が発生されてます。
同じソースコードを別のアプリにリリースしたら、OKです。
別の端末は無事にプッシュ通知の受信が可能。

現状は端末IDの復号化処理で例外が発生されSalesforceプッシュ通知サーバーの端末ID登録が失敗されます。
ログは下記のようです。
お手数ですが解決方法をご存知の方、よろしくお願いします。

```
E  keystore2::error: In KeystoreOperation::finish   
    
Caused by:  
0: In finish: KeyMint::finish failed.   
1: Error::Km(ErrorCode(-1000))  
E  Error during asymmetric decryption   
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException  
at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:613)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2056)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.security.Encryptor.decryptWithPrivateKey(Encryptor.java:530)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.security.Encryptor.decryptWithRSABytes(Encryptor.java:427)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.security.Encryptor.decryptWithRSA(Encryptor.java:408)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.generateUniqueId(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:164)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.getUniqueId(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:88)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.getUniqueId(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:77)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.generateEncryptionKey(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:145)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.getEncryptionKey(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:103)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.app.SalesforceSDKManager.getEncryptionKey(SalesforceSDKManager.java:1082)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.accounts.UserAccountManager.getCurrentAccount(UserAccountManager.java:224)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.accounts.UserAccountManager.getCurrentUser(UserAccountManager.java:174)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.accounts.UserAccountManager.getCachedCurrentUser(UserAccountManager.java:188)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.AnalyticsPublisherService.handleActionPublish(AnalyticsPublisherService.java:76)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.AnalyticsPublisherService.onHandleWork(AnalyticsPublisherService.java:67)
at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:396)
at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:387)
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Unknown error    
at android.security.KeyStore2.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore2.java:356)
at android.security.KeyStoreOperation.handleExceptions(KeyStoreOperation.java:78)
at android.security.KeyStoreOperation.finish(KeyStoreOperation.java:127)
at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer$MainDataStream.finish(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:228)
at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:181)
at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:603)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2056) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.security.Encryptor.decryptWithPrivateKey(Encryptor.java:530) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.security.Encryptor.decryptWithRSABytes(Encryptor.java:427) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.security.Encryptor.decryptWithRSA(Encryptor.java:408) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.generateUniqueId(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:164) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.getUniqueId(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:88) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.getUniqueId(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:77) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.generateEncryptionKey(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:145) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.getEncryptionKey(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:103) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.app.SalesforceSDKManager.getEncryptionKey(SalesforceSDKManager.java:1082) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.accounts.UserAccountManager.getCurrentAccount(UserAccountManager.java:224) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.accounts.UserAccountManager.getCurrentUser(UserAccountManager.java:174) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.accounts.UserAccountManager.getCachedCurrentUser(UserAccountManager.java:188) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.AnalyticsPublisherService.handleActionPublish(AnalyticsPublisherService.java:76) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.AnalyticsPublisherService.onHandleWork(AnalyticsPublisherService.java:67) 
at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:396) 
at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:387) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 
E  Exception thrown while getting encryption key    
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)' on a null object reference    
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.generateEncryptionKey(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:146)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.getEncryptionKey(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:103)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.app.SalesforceSDKManager.getEncryptionKey(SalesforceSDKManager.java:1082)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.accounts.UserAccountManager.getCurrentAccount(UserAccountManager.java:224)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.accounts.UserAccountManager.getCurrentUser(UserAccountManager.java:174)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.accounts.UserAccountManager.getCachedCurrentUser(UserAccountManager.java:188)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.AnalyticsPublisherService.handleActionPublish(AnalyticsPublisherService.java:76)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.AnalyticsPublisherService.onHandleWork(AnalyticsPublisherService.java:67)
at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:396)
at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:387)
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
E  rsp_header->status: -1000    
E  keystore2::error: In KeystoreOperation::finish   
    
Caused by:  
0: In finish: KeyMint::finish failed.   
1: Error::Km(ErrorCode(-1000))  

E  Error during asymmetric decryption   
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException  
at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:613)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2056)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.security.Encryptor.decryptWithPrivateKey(Encryptor.java:530)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.security.Encryptor.decryptWithRSABytes(Encryptor.java:427)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.security.Encryptor.decryptWithRSA(Encryptor.java:408)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.generateUniqueId(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:164)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.getUniqueId(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:88)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.getUniqueId(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:77)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.push.PushService.getRSAPublicKey(PushService.java:354)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.push.PushService.registerSFDCPushNotification(PushService.java:309)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.push.PushService.onRegistered(PushService.java:216)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.push.PushService.performRegistrationChange(PushService.java:184)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.push.PushService.onHandleWork(PushService.java:174)
at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:396)
at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:387)
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.security.Exception: Unknown error    
at android.security.KeyStore2.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore2.java:356)
at android.security.KeyStoreOperation.handleExceptions(KeyStoreOperation.java:78)
at android.security.KeyStoreOperation.finish(KeyStoreOperation.java:127)
at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer$MainDataStream.finish(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:228)
at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:181)
at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:603)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2056) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.security.Encryptor.decryptWithPrivateKey(Encryptor.java:530) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.security.Encryptor.decryptWithRSABytes(Encryptor.java:427) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.analytics.security.Encryptor.decryptWithRSA(Encryptor.java:408) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.generateUniqueId(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:164) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.getUniqueId(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:88) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.security.SalesforceKeyGenerator.getUniqueId(SalesforceKeyGenerator.java:77) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.push.PushService.getRSAPublicKey(PushService.java:354) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.push.PushService.registerSFDCPushNotification(PushService.java:309) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.push.PushService.onRegistered(PushService.java:216) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.push.PushService.performRegistrationChange(PushService.java:184) 
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.push.PushService.onHandleWork(PushService.java:174) 
at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:396) 
at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:387) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 


 E  Push notification registration failed   
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference  
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.push.PushService.getRSAPublicKey(PushService.java:355)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.push.PushService.registerSFDCPushNotification(PushService.java:309)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.push.PushService.onRegistered(PushService.java:216)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.push.PushService.performRegistrationChange(PushService.java:184)
at com.salesforce.androidsdk.push.PushService.onHandleWork(PushService.java:174)
at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:396)
at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:387)
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```